# ASP.NET: Check if run from migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have some code in my `ConfigureServices` that fails when running a migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations list
```

I'm trying to add a Certificate but it can't find the file (it works when starting the project as a whole). So is there a way to do something like this:

```
if (!CurrentEnvironment.IsMigration()) {
    doMyStuffThatFailsInMigration()
}
```

That way I could keep my code as it is but just execute it when not running it in a migration.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Just set a static flag in the Main method (which is not called by the dotnet-ef tool):

```
public class Program
{
    public static bool IsStartedWithMain { get; private set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IsStartedWithMain = true;
        ...
    }
}
```

and then check it when needed:

```
internal static void ConfigureServices(WebHostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (Program.IsStartedWithMain)
    {
        // do stuff which must not be run upon using the dotnet-ef tool
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: in Dotnet 6.0 there's no separate `ConfigureServices` method. Everything is initialized in the Main method (can be created with `dotnet new .. --use-program-main`). In this case a flag can be used for skipping EF stuff:

```cs
private static bool IsStartedWithMain =>
    Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() == Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

Comment: In dotnet 6 there no Main. How can we flag it from Program.cs?

Comment: I'd also like to know how to do this when we are using just Program.cs with no Startup.cs

Comment: with netcore 6+, we can detect it by examining the environment CommandLine:
`private static bool ExecutedByMigration { get; set; }
private static string EfToolFlag = "ef.dll ";   // ef.dll database update || ef.dll migration add || ef.dll migration remove
      public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var commandLine = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Environment.CommandLine);
            if (commandLine.Contains(EfToolFlag)) ExecutedByMigration = true;`

Answer (score 4):

My current solution to detecting if a migration has not occurred:

```
using System.Linq;
// app is of type IApplicationBuilder
// RegisteredDBContext is the DBContext I have dependency injected
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<RegisteredDBContext>();
            if (context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
            {
                var msg = "There are pending migrations application will not start. Make sure migrations are ran.";
                throw new InvalidProgramException(msg);
                // Instead of error throwing, other code could happen
            }
        }
```

This assumes that the migrations have been synced to the database already. If only `EnsureDatabase` has been called, then this approach does not work, because the migrations are all still pending.

There are other method options on the `context.Database`. `GetMigrations` and `GetAppliedMigrations`.

Comment: The question is not about whether a migration has occured or not. It's about runtime environment, i.e. whether the current process is normal hosting or the dotnet-ef tool applying a migration.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue, I wish migrations automatically set the environment as "Migration" instead of "Development".

You can try this as it worked for me using .Net 7:

```
if (!Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Contains("migrations") && 
    !Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Contains("database"))
{
    // Add roles to db on startup for example.
}
```

Thanks Nikolai Koudelia for the idea in one of the previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
bool isMigrations = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0].Contains("ef.dll");
```